# Object event after attribute update

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example code:

```
class objval(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        #run some function AFTER attribute is set

    test = objval()
    test.a = 2
```

The issue with the above is `def __setattr__(self, name, value):` runs before not after. Is there an event that fires after an object attribute change?

Comment: what you mean by "runs before not after"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do some operation with set-attr *after* the value is set:

```
class Objval(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

        #run some function AFTER attribute is set
        print(f"doing something here, name is '{name}' value is '{value}'")

test = Objval()
test.a = 2
```

The output of this code is:

```
doing something here, name is 'a' value is '1'
doing something here, name is 'a' value is '2'
```